# How to organize the project view in Pycharm differently from the physical file system

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm

I have a question related to the project organization in PyCharm.

Not sure if what I want to achieve is even doable. My research on project organization and virtual file system did not lead me to any usable hint so far. Since I am also not very familiar with Pycharm or IntelliJ IDEs, the main problem is probably that I don't know what exactly I need to search.

I see that in the IDE there is the view on the physical file system, and the project view which can be organized differently.

I have a folder structure on my file system which looks like this:

```
root
  |-A lot of chunk I am not interested in
  |
  |-Folder 1
  |  |-subfolder 1
  |    |-exampleModule
  |    | |-code.py
  |    |-anotherModule
  |    | |-code.py
  |
  |-Folder 2
  |  |-same structure as folder 1
  |
  |- more folders...
```

Now in the pycharm project view i would like to display it like this:

```
root
  |-Folder 1
  |  |-exampleModule.py
  |  |-anotherModule.py
  |
  |-Folder 2
  |  |-same structure as folder 1
```

To achieve this I need to

- ignore some files in the project view
- reorganize the folder structure
- rename the code.py files to the parent folder name

Can this be achieved somehow and if yes, could it also be automated? Or do I completely misunderstand the project view functionality in PyCharm?

You might ask why I don't just organize my code differently. The folder structure is generated by the Ignition SCADA system and can not be changed. However I would like to be able to edit the code in Pycharm and display it as it is displayed in the Ignition designer.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest two solutions:

1. Open "Folder 1" as a project.

2A. Open "Folder 2" as another project and select "Attach".

2B. Attach "Folder 2" as a content root in your [project structure settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/project-structure-dialog.html).